# Google Allo Style Compose Message Area

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, chat

I am trying to create Google Allo style Compose message chat area in html and css and i looked at allo.google.com/web their web version of allo and i created mine [here](https://codepen.io/CaptainTeemo/pen/ZXBvPa) but the problem i am facing is my text area is scrolling horizontally beyond my container `div` and i couldn't figure it out whats causing it.I already tried adusting the width but its not the kind of solution i am looking for.

You guys can login to https://allo.google.com/web and see their send message area inside the chat screen. I am tru=ying to replicate that exactly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` has a default margin set to around `8px`. Remove it with:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

to get rid of the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: actually the body margin is only set in the codepen demo but in my actual projet it set to 0. but still it is not working.